# php / mysql pagination

Tags: php

I have a table with 58 records in mysql database.  I was able to connect to my database and retrive all records and made 5 pages with links to view each pages using php script.

webpage will look like this:

```
name    number
john    1232343456
tony    9878768544
jack    3454562345
joe     1232343456
jane    2343454567
andy    2344560987
marcy   9873459876
sean    8374623534
mark    9898787675
nancy   8374650493

1 2 3 4 5
```

that's the first page of 58 records and those 5 numbers at bottom are links to each page that will display next 10 records.  I got all that.  but what I want to do is display the links in this way:

```
1-10  11-20  21-30  31-40  41-50  51-58
```

note:  since i have 58 records, last link will display upto 58, instead of 60.

Since I used the loop  to create this link, depending on how many records i have, the link will change according to the number of records in my table.  How can i do this?

Thanks.

EDIT:  since first page is already displaying, 1-10 will not be a link.  same goes for other pages.  whatever page is displaying, that link will not be a link.

EDIT2:  this is my code for those links

```
$limit=10;
if($totalrecords > $limit )
{
  echo "<table align = 'center' width='50%'><tr>";
  // Display the page links at center.  Current page will not be a link.
  echo "<td align=center width='30%'>";
  $i=0;
  $l=1;

  for($i=0;$i < $totalrecords;$i=$i+$limit)
  {
    if($i <> $current)
    {
      echo " <a href='$page_name?start=$i'>$l</a> ";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "$l";
    }
    $l=$l+1;   // Current page is not displayed as link.
  }
  echo "</td></tr></table>";
}
```

in this code, each page links display as:

```
1  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: Have you tried search SO for the paginaton?

Comment: Luis, I thought I put the real question there.  Instead of having the page links as 1 2 3 4 5, I would like it to look like: 1-10  11-20  21-30  31-40  41-50  51-58.  And depending on the total number of records, the last link will change according to the number of records.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should help:

```
<?php

$results_per_page = 10;
$results_count = 58;

foreach(
  array_chunk(
    (array)range(1, $results_count),
    $results_per_page
  ) 
  as $page_number => $results
){

  $begin = array_slice($results, 0, 1);
  $end = array_slice($results, -1, 1);

  echo "<a href=\"?page={$page_number}\">",
    $begin[0],"-",$end[0],
  "</a>\n"; 
}

?>
```

#### Output

```
<a href="?page=0">1-10</a>
<a href="?page=1">11-20</a>
<a href="?page=2">21-30</a>
<a href="?page=3">31-40</a>
<a href="?page=4">41-50</a>
<a href="?page=5">51-58</a>
```

Comment: thank you. it's displaying the links the way i wanted it to. however, when i click the link 11-20, it's supposed to display records from 11-20, but instead it's displaying records from 2-11. likewise, other links also increment by just one records.  at least, the links are showing right...LOL.  just need to make the link to display correct records according to the links.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code really depends on something that you already have, but the algorithm would be something like this:

1. Get the count of the total records
2. Divide the total records amount by the pagination size (in this case is 10)
3. Use the remainder (or module) so the last would appear as the last page.

Would be better if you post some code.

The links would be something like this

```
<a href="?page=5">50-58</a>
```

I think I am missing the point on the question.

Comment: i think my question could be lacking something...but i don't want to hard code the link by typing 50-58. i'm sure i might be answering my own question, but i just can't get the grip on this. i want the loop to limit 10 records per page and let the last page link to be whatever the total record is. so if the total record in the table is 58, the last page link will be 50-58. or if the total record is 62, the link will be 61-62. i hope this is more clear.